# Attached icon to radcomobox

Tags: c#, vb.net, telerik, radcombobox

Does someone might know how can I attached icon to RadComobobox here is my code:

I hope that someone can give me direction or example that working....thanks

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbJobType" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Select Job Type" Width="248px">
                                  <Items>
                                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Select Job Type" Value="Select Job Type" />
                                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Long Term" Value="Long Term" />
                                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Short Term" Value="Short Term" />
                                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Last Minute" Value="Last Minute" />
                                  </Items>
</telerik:RadComboBox>


occurs on pageload
      Protected Sub IconAttached()
                Dim imgDir As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Images/Layout/offDuty.png")))
                For Each file As FileInfo In imgDir.GetFiles("*.png")
                    Dim item As New RadComboBoxItem(file.Name.Replace(".png", ""))
                    item.ImageUrl = "Img/" + file.Name
                    rcbEditJobType.Items.Add(item)

                Next
               = "<img src='" + Globals.gRootRelativeSecureURL("/Images/Layout/offDuty.png") + "' border=""0"" align=""absmiddle"">"
    End Sub
```

Comment: You should ask that in their forums : http://www.telerik.com/support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

**ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="RadComboBox1"> 
     <Items>
           <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Select Job Type" Value="Select Job Type" />
           <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Long Term" Value="Long Term" />
           <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Short Term" Value="Short Term" />
           <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Last Minute" Value="Last Minute" />
     </Items>
     <ItemTemplate> 
           <div> 
                <asp:Image ID="Image1"  runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'  runat="server">
           </div> 
     </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

**ASPX.VB**

```
For Each item As RadComboBoxItem In RadComboBox1.Items
    Dim Image1 As Image = DirectCast(item.FindControl("Image1"), CheckBox)
    Image1.ImageUrl = "Please add image url here"
Next
```